# How to pass value from one page to another page using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to jQuery. I want to pass value from one page to another page using jQuery. I have also javascript code for passing this value. But I want to do the same things using jQuery.

My php and Javascript code is as below

PHP Code:

```
          <?php
            for ($i=1; $i<count($array)+1; $i++) {
          ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php print_s($array[$i]['open_date']); ?></td>

              <td style="width: 120px" ><?php print_s($array[$i]['group']); ?></td>
              <td style="width: 150px" ><?php print_s($array[$i]['division']); ?></td>
              <td style="width:  30px" ><?php print_s($array[$i]['control_no_parent']); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="group[<?php print_s($i); ?>]"             id="group[<?php print_s($i); ?>]"             value="<?php print_s($array[$i]['group']); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="division[<?php print_s($i); ?>]"          id="division[<?php print_s($i); ?>]"          value="<?php print_s($array[$i]['division']); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="control_no_parent[<?php print_s($i); ?>]" id="control_no_parent[<?php print_s($i); ?>]" value="<?php print_s($array[$i]['control_no_parent']); ?>" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php print_s($array[$i]['control_no_child']); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="control_no_child[<?php print_s($i); ?>]"  id="control_no_child[<?php print_s($i); ?>]"  value="<?php print_s($array[$i]['control_no_child']); ?>" />
              </td>
              <td><?php print_s($array[$i]['title']); ?></td>
              <td><input type="submit" name="disp_btn[<?php print_s($i); ?>]" class="w50" value="表 示" onClick = "tekeOver(<?php print_s($i); ?>)"/></td>
            </tr>
          <?php
            }
          ?>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function tekeOver(RowNo) {

  document.getElementById('RowNo').value             = RowNo
  document.getElementById('group').value             = document.getElementById('group[' + RowNo + ']').value
  document.getElementById('division').value          = document.getElementById('division[' + RowNo + ']').value
  document.getElementById('control_no_parent').value = document.getElementById('control_no_parent[' + RowNo + ']').value
  document.getElementById('control_no_child').value  = document.getElementById('control_no_child[' + RowNo + ']').value
}
```

Comment: Why not use a PHP session? No need for jQuery

Comment: So are you basically just asking how to change the `tekeOver()` function to use `$().val()` instead of `document.getElementById().value`? If so, any introductory jQuery tutorial will cover that.

Comment: you can use local storage or session storage

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I am learning jquery. I have also tried but jquery returns a null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion，we have some ways.
Firstly, we can use cookie if we don't care the suporting of the browser.
The first page:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Another page:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie');
```

Of course, we need jquery plugin jquery.cookie.js
What's more, we can transfer value in url.

Comment: Is it possible by calling function like javascript? For example here I have called takeover() function.

Comment: You can also just called takeover() function. But to replace    document.getElementById to $() , such as         document.getElementById('RowNo').value = RowNo to $('#RowNo').val(RowNo)

Comment: $('#RowNo').val(RowNo) is working. But when I am calling var group = $('#group[' + RowNo + ']').val(); $('#group').val(group); it is not working.

Comment: It there 'group' a param?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Now it is working. I have changed my php code. id="group[<?php print_s($i); ?>]" to id="group<?php print_s($i); ?>"  . Now it is working fine.